# Page Redirect On Page_Load IF Record Exists

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, pageload

Ok, I have an default.aspx page that I'm trying to have redirect the user to a different page depending on whether or not their deviceId is stored in the SQL Server database.  It should direct the user to the login.aspx if the record for the user is found or to the newdevice.aspx page if there was no record found.  I want this to occur on Page_Load but have not been able to figure it out so far.

Comment: What do you mean by device id? Are you talking about a mobile device? Are you talking about a device id which uniquely identify each mobile phone or do you want to get the model number or something similar? Which part are you stuck in? How is the device id stored in the database before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic idea on how to do it :)

```
Sub Page_Load()
{

//Acquire the User ID or email etc which can uniquely identify the user

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(deviceId) from DeviceIDTable WHERE UserID=UserID",con);

if (cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString() != "1") 
{
   Response.Redirect("newdevice.aspx");
}
else 
{
   Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing what exactly you are looking for, but in order to redirect a page you may invoke Response.Redirect as follows:

```
  Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)

    //Processing to figure out if deciveId is stored in database

    If deviceIdFound Then
      Response.Redirect("newdevice.aspx")
    Else
      Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    End If
  End Sub
```

If the question is actually tied to FormsAuthentication or somthing else regarding the Sql Database lookup etc please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You have two primary options for handling this situation. You can use Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer.

It is recommended that you use Server.Transfer for internal redirects and Response.Redirect for external redirects as [Server.Transfer leads to a lighter server load and fits the ASP.NET work flow better](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2004/07/21/189547.aspx). Server.Transfer cannot transfer to External pages and, as such, isn't useful for transfers outside of the same application.

You can use Server.Transfer with a code block similar to below:

```
If User.IsValid = False Then
Server.Transfer("~/Login.aspx")
End If
```

If you need to use Response.Redirect instead it would be usable with a code block similar to below:

```
If User.IsValid = False Then
Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx",True)
End If
```

The True parameter instructs the ASP.NET runtime to end processing of the current page and send the redirect immediately.

Comment: I couldn't cite another source in the same post due to being a new user so I'll post it here. A little more information on the difference between Server.Transfer and Response.Redirect.

http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641/ServerTransfer-Vs-ResponseRedirect.htm